# Exception binding variables with cx_Oracle in python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Okay, so I'm connected to an oracle database in python 2.7 and cx_Oracle 5.1 compiled against the instant client 11.2. I've got a cursor to the database and running SQL is not an issue, except this:

```
    cursor.execute('ALTER TRIGGER :schema_trigger_name DISABLE',
                     schema_trigger_name='test.test_trigger')
```

or

```
    cursor.prepare('ALTER TRIGGER :schema_trigger_name DISABLE')
    cursor.execute(None,{'schema_trigger_name': 'test.test_trigger'})
```

both result in an error from oracle:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "connect.py", line 257, in 
        cursor.execute('ALTER TRIGGER :schema_trigger_name DISABLE',
                    schema_trigger_name='test.test_trigger')
    cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

While running:

```
    cursor.execute('ALTER TRIGGER test.test_trigger DISABLE')
```

works perfectly. What's the issue with binding that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `test.test_trigger` is not a variable but an object. You can only bind variables (that can be replaced by a value).

The query you are trying to run would be logically equivalent to:

```
ALTER TRIGGER 'test.test_trigger' DISABLE
```

Binding in this case won't work, you will have to build the query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You normally can't bind an object name in Oracle. For variables it'll work but not for trigger_names, table_names etc.